# create a json from a soap response in java

Tags: java, json, xml, web-services, soap

I have a REST web service which in turn calls a Soap request. I want to convert the soap response into a json so that it can be returned as output to the REST service. What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

To elaborate the question, suppose I get a Soap xml response like given below.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/" soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
    <soap:Body xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/stock">
        <m:GetStockPriceResponse>
            <m:Price>344.5</m:Price>
        </m:GetStockPriceResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I want the json to be like this

{"price" : "344.5"}

I have tried the org.json.XML.toJSONObject() method. But it does not give the output I expect.

Comment: There won't be a single library that gives you the expected output. You will need to write a filter yourself based on an XML parser, where you would manually map each required value to its key.

Comment: Lookup Jersey, it can convert Java POJO into JSON and vice versa. So if you have a POJO that represents the XML entity then you're sorted. However the JSON string output might not be as what you're expected.

Comment: The original response which i am trying to convert is very large and contains a lot of data. So i am concerned about performance while writing a filter of my own. Is there any standard way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
public String XMLtoJSON(String xml) {
    JSONObject jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
    String json = jsonObj.toString();
    return json;
}
```

Comment: Yes.  But it will not be a pure json like what i mentioned as output.  It will convert the soap tags as well to json

Comment: Does the convertion anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Java 8** or later, you should check out my open source library: [unXml](https://github.com/tajakobsen/unxml). unXml basically maps from Xpaths to Json-attributes.

It's available on [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cunxml).

*Example*

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import com.nerdforge.unxml.factory.ParsingFactory;
import com.nerdforge.unxml.parsers.Parser;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class Parser {
  public ObjectNode parseXml(String xml){
    Parsing parsing = ParsingFactory.getInstance(namespaces()).create();
    Document document = parsing.xml().document(xml);

    Parser<ObjectNode> parser = parsing.obj("//m:GetStockPriceResponse")
        .attribute("price", "m:Price", parsing.number())
        .build();

    ObjectNode result = parser.apply(document);
    return result;
  }

  private Map<String, String> namespaces(){
    return new HashMap<String, String>(){{
        put("m", "http://www.example.org/stock");
    }};
  }
}
```

It will return a [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) `ObjectNode`, with the following json:

```
{"price":344.5}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you already use [Jakarta XML Web Services](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.jaxws) and [Jakarta XML Binding](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.jaxb-impl). Your class annotated `jakarta.ws.WebService` turns Java objects into XML implicitly into your methods annotated `jakarta.ws.WebMethod` and returning instances of Java beans. You can simply pass those instances to [Jakarta JSON Binding](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.jsonb):

```
import jakarta.ejb.Stateless;
import jakarta.jws.WebMethod;
import jakarta.jws.WebParam;
import jakarta.jws.WebService;
import jakarta.json.bind.Jsonb;
import jakarta.json.bind.JsonbBuilder;

@Stateless
@WebService
public class Manager {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "getMyJavaBeanAsJson")
    public String getMyJavaBeanAsJson(@WebParam(name = "id") final BigDecimal id) {
        final MyJavaBean myJavaBeanInstance = MyJavaBeanService.getInstance().find(id);
        try (final Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create()) {
            return jsonb.toJson(myJavaBeanInstance);
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that my answer uses only standard Jakarta EE (>= 9) APIs with no third party dependencies.

Another solution consists in using Java Stax (Java API for XML Processing) to read the SOAP envelope, the SOAP body, the SOAP response, the SOAP return and then to turn only this part of the received XML into JSON. Either convert XML into a Java bean and use the solution above to turn in into JSON or turn the XML into JSON without using a Java bean. In my humble opinion, if you don't want to return the SOAP stuff in your JSON, use Stax to get only the SOAP return and pass it to `org.json.XML.toJSONObject(final String xml)` or any other tool able to convert XML to JSON.